# Suppress OutputRedirector text from Apache Spark log

Tags: apache-spark, logging

In my spark application I am logging like this:

```
Logger log = spark.log();

log.info("**************************************************");
log.info("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);
log.info("**************************************************");
```

However, my logs currently look like this:

```
Apr 24, 2017 10:54:38 PM org.apache.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector redirect
INFO: [CJC]17/04/24 22:54:38 INFO SparkSession: **************************************************
Apr 24, 2017 10:54:38 PM org.apache.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector redirect
INFO: [CJC]17/04/24 22:54:38 INFO SparkSession: Pi is roughly 3.138936
Apr 24, 2017 10:54:38 PM org.apache.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector redirect
INFO: [CJC]17/04/24 22:54:38 INFO SparkSession: **************************************************
```

I would like it to clean this up so it looks like this:

```
INFO: [CJC]17/04/24 22:54:38 INFO SparkSession: **************************************************
INFO: [CJC]17/04/24 22:54:38 INFO SparkSession: Pi is roughly 3.138936
INFO: [CJC]17/04/24 22:54:38 INFO SparkSession: **************************************************
```

In this case the log4j.properties file doesn't seem to help me as it seems all logging is going through the OutputRedirector class.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: did you manage to suppress thses messages?

Comment: Did you manage to suppress the redirect text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tldr;

To suppress the header

`Apr 24, 2017 10:54:38 PM org.apache.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector redirect`:

**Add this to your code**
`System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format","%5$s%6$s%n");`

---

Running Spark in `client`mode against a standalone spark cluster uses 2 logging frameworks.

- java.util.logger used by `org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher`
- the embedded driver's logging framework bound to slf4j. In  my case it was log4j.

To control the format of the embbed driver's logging, use the following
System properties as mentioned in an earlier answer:

- `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:<path>/log4j.xml`
- `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:<path>/log4j.xml`

**To suppress the `Apr 24, 2017 10:54:38 PM org.apache.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector redirect`**:

1. Redirect the embedded driver logs to a logger

```
sparkLauncher.redirectToLog(createLogger("spark-pi"));

private java.util.logging.Logger createLogger(String appName) throws IOException {
    final java.util.logging.Logger logger = getRootLogger();
    final FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("./" + appName + "-%u-%g.log", 10_000_000, 5, true);
    handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(handler);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    return logger;
}

private java.util.logging.Logger getRootLogger() {
    final java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(java.util.logging.Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    Arrays.stream(logger.getHandlers()).forEach(logger::removeHandler);
    //Without this the logging will go to the Console and to a file.
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    return logger;
}
```

2. `System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format","%5$s%6$s%n");`

This changes SimpleFormatter's default logging pattern. See [jdk docs](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/tip/src/java.logging/share/classes/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.java).

Comment: Setting the SimpleFormatter's default logging pattern worked great for me.  Thank you very much !!!  You are a rock star.

Comment: Not sure why it prints such header. I do not see any value except making it difficult to read. Just wasting everyone's life to hack it.